# Specifying lifetimes in macro derives

Tags: rust, lifetime

How does one specify lifetimes on macro derives?

```
#[derive(ElasticType, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Xkcd<'a> {
       link: &'a str
}
```

Error example:

```
#[derive(ElasticType, Serialize, Deserialize)]
 |       ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your piece of code you simply can not fix this issue. It's a bug in the crate providing `#[derive(ElasticType)]`.

File a bug with the author of `ElasticType`! If it's not possible for some reason to add support for lifetimed struct it should at least emit a useful error message stating so.